# Address Inquiry

Tags: pointers, programming-languages, memory-address

Okay so, lets say I have an integer.
When I execute the program, that integer gets an address.

Makes sense.

But, there is many programs out there. Lets see, when creating any game hack, lets say minesweeper I find address of where that data stored and change it.

But... That hack, that simple hack which just changing some address... Works on every computer and every-time.

The question is, that data is getting same address every-time.
And on my computer, there is about 30 exe running now.
Don't other programs want that address ? What If they want that address ? Why that hack works every-time ? Why other programs dont want that very same address ? How its working every-time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every application gets it's own virtual addressing space (4GB on 32 bit machines) to overcome that problem in a multitasking operating system.

Here is a pretty good [article](http://www.tenouk.com/WinVirtualAddressSpace.html) covering the subject.

Your "hack" is probably locating a process using something like [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and editing the memory using [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That's why it works on "all" machines.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to read about [*virtual memory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).  The purpose of virtual memory is to abstract away the physical address space, and give each process (i.e. each application) its own "virtual" address space, which avoids the problem that you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

If your minesweeper hack consists of manipulating data stored on a specified static address, there's no way it would work on every computer.. Program memory allocation is OS dependent.

Comment: then explain why game-hacks works on every computer ?  edit: did you mean that windows 7 hack will work on windows 7 but not another OS?

Comment: Yes and no. Its possible that windows 7 will allocate the same addresses for similar applications..but even that's not very likely. I doubt game-hacks work like that. They probably find the addresses they need by working with its processes.